# How to update memcached to 1.4.33 on centos? Yum says there is no update

Tags: centos, centos7, memcached

I need to update memcached on centos7 from 1.4.15 to 1.4.33 however yum update says there isn't anything to update, clearly there is as there is a newer version. I can't find anything on google explaining how to update it, it's all just about installing it with yum install memcached - which doesn't install the latest!

```
yum update memcached
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 93.115.203.100
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 93.115.203.100
 * cpanel-plugins: 93.115.203.100
No packages marked for update
```

Comment: You don't. At least not from the repositories, as [CentOS 7 is End Of Life](https://endoflife.date/centos) and only get security patches. You won't get new versions on it.

Comment: @vidarlo CentOS 7 is still supported, it will reach it's end of life in 2024. It is however correct that it will only receive security patches and no new versions.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Agree, my wording was a bit off. Sorry for that :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 7 only receives security fixes, no updates anymore.

You can upgrade your machine to a newer version of CentOS (or install one of the forks that started with RedHats switch to the Stream releases) or you can install a newer version of memcached using a container.

Comment: a container such as docker?

Comment: Whatever flavor you prefer.

Comment: ok thanks accepted your answer